# CMake Header only wrapper library

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I currently have the following project structure

```
internal code../../
API/
  C/
    CMakeList.txt
    headers...h
    Sources/
      sources...cpp
  CPP/
    CMakeList.txt
    headers...hpp
  Example/
    CMakeList.txt
    main.cpp
```

Where `API/C/..` contains a c interface for the central project, `API/CPP/..` contains a header only wrapper around the c-interface and `API/Example` contains example usage of the API.

I cannot get the `API/CPP/CMakeList.txt` to work. I tried to make it an `INTERFACE` but the includes don't seem to work.

for example consider

- `API/C/test.h`
- `API/CPP/test.hpp`

Then I can `#include` both files in `main.cpp` but I can't `#include API/C/test.h` inside `API/CPP/test.hpp`

`API/C/CMakeList.txt` contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4 )

include ( ...Dependencies... )

project(API VERSION 0.0.1)

set(
    API_C_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES
        ...
)

set(
    API_C_Headers
        test.h
        ...
)

set (
    API_C_Private_Headers
        ...
)

set(
    API_C_Sources
        Sources/test.cpp
)

add_library(
    API_C SHARED
        ${API_C_Headers}
        ${API_C_Private_Headers}
        ${API_C_Sources}
)

set_target_properties(
    API_C PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
)

target_link_libraries(
    API_C
        ${API_C_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES}

)

# Copy dll, etc
foreach( DYNAMIC_LIBRARY ${API_C_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES} )
    add_custom_command( TARGET API_C POST_BUILD COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "$<TARGET_FILE:${DYNAMIC_LIBRARY}>" $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:API_C> )
    add_custom_command( TARGET API_C POST_BUILD COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:${DYNAMIC_LIBRARY}>" $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:API_C> )
endforeach()



set_property( TARGET API_C PROPERTY FOLDER "API" )

source_group(
    "Private Header Files" FILES ${API_C_Private_Headers}
)
```

`API/CPP/CMakeList.txt` contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4 )

project(API VERSION 0.0.1)

set(
    API_CPP_Headers
        test.hpp
        ...
)

add_library(
        API_CPP INTERFACE ${API_CPP_Headers}
)
target_include_directories(API_CPP INTERFACE . )

target_link_libraries(
        API_CPP INTERFACE
        API_C
)

set_target_properties(
        API_CPP PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
)

set_property( TARGET API_CPP PROPERTY FOLDER "API" )
```

`API/CPP/CMakeList.txt` contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4 )

project(API VERSION 0.0.1)

set(
    API_EXAMPLE_Headers
)

set (
    API_EXAMPLE_Private_Headers
)

set(
    API_EXAMPLE_Sources
        main.cpp
)

add_library(
        API_EXAMPLE SHARED
        ${API_EXAMPLE_Headers}
        ${API_EXAMPLE_Private_Headers}
        ${API_EXAMPLE_Sources}
)

set_target_properties(
        API_EXAMPLE PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
)

target_link_libraries(
        API_EXAMPLE
        INTERFACE API_CPP
)

set_property( TARGET API_EXAMPLE PROPERTY FOLDER "API" )

source_group(
    "Private Header Files" FILES ${API_EXAMPLE_Private_Headers}
)
```

Comment: You haven't added `target_include_directories` for the `API_C` target

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a directory structure like this, since this way you cannot reasonably limit the visibility of headers: If you need `#include "API/C/test.h"` to work, `#include "API/Example/main.cpp"` would work too as would `#include "API/CPP/CMakeLists.txt"`. I recommend something like `API/C/include/API/C/test.h` or preferrable one less directories below the `include` dir which is common with most libs. Also IIRC interface libs may not work with relative paths so it may be necessary to replace `.` with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..`.